# How to generate a variable that records entry into a study using an age variable in a longitudinal dataset?

Tags: r, if-statement

I essentially have a longitudinal dataset and this includes 8 waves of data collection. So I have 8 age variables `age_1:age_8` and if a participant enters at wave 1, their age is recorded in `age_1` and otherwise its set as NA. Similarly, if the participants have entered the study at wave 2, their age is recorded in `age_2` and the follow-up age of the participants that entered in the previous wave (wave 1) is also recorded but if the participant enters in a subsequent wave (not wave 1 or 2) their age is listed as NA. So I hope this somewhat elucidates what the data consists of. What I want to do is create a variable that records just the age that the individual entered into the study.

What I have tried to do is something like this (I know its awful) which is just statements to say for example in `entry_2`, if the `age_2` (wave 2) is NA and `age_1` is not NA then entry is recorded as NA but otherwise it takes the value recorded for age at wave 2 as the entry. So I'm trying to just take the age of the individuals that entered in that particular wave and exclude any follow-up ages from the previous waves that may have been recorded. But this doesn't work as it just replicates the age variable as shown in the example below.

````
data$entry_2 <- ifelse(is.na(data$age_2) & !is.na(data$age_1), NA, data$age_2)
data$entry_3 <- ifelse(is.na(data$age_3) & !is.na(data$age_1) & !is.na(data$age_2), NA, data$age_3)```

Output: 

summary(data$entry_2)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
12.00   58.00   69.00   64.64   72.00  102.00    9076 

summary(data$age_2)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
12.00   58.00   69.00   64.64   72.00  102.00    9076
````

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you what you need:

```
first_entry <- function(subj) {
    na.omit(subj)[1]
}

age_df <- data.frame(
    age_1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA),
    age_2 = c(1, NA, 3, NA),
    age_3 = c(2, NA, 4, 4),
    age_4 = c(3, 4, 5, 5)
)

  age_1 age_2 age_3 age_4
1    NA     1     2     3
2    NA    NA    NA     4
3     1     3     4     5
4    NA    NA     4     5

youngest <- apply(age_df, 1, first_entry)

youngest
[1] 1 4 1 4
```

Comment: `na.omit(x)[1]` is an easier way to get first non-missing entry of a vector.

Comment: @AdamO Good call, thanks! Edited to reflect this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The last paragraph gets a little confusing regarding what specifically you're looking for, but it will probably be better to use `dplyr` and `tidyr` here to accomplish this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#' Example data
test = data.frame(participant = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), age_1 = c(NA, 10, NA, NA), age_2 = c(14, 11, NA, NA), age_3 = c(NA, 12, NA, 16), age_4 = c(NA, 14, 10, 17), age_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
test2 <- test %>% gather(key = "wave", value = "age", -participant) %>% group_by(participant) %>% mutate(previous_age = lag(age)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(is_entry = ifelse(is.na(previous_age) & !is.na(age), 1, 0)) %>% select(-previous_age)
```

This will give you 4 columns: the participant, which wave it is, the age at that wave and whether or not that wave was the entry for that participant. From here you can do your analysis, grouping by wave and is_entry to get the summaries.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for age presented in a long data format.

```
id wave age
 1    1   3
 1    2   6
 1    3   9
 1    4  10
 2    1  NA
 2    2  NA
 2    3   5
 2    4   9
```

Is

```
tapply(df$age, df$id, min, na.rm=F)
```

to get

```
[1] 3 5
```